# pixelate image texture when applied to material

Tags: ios, uiimage, scenekit

I'm assigning an image to custom material. The image assigned looks somewhat pixelate, similar to this image

[image]

I have already set the antialiasing to 4x. How do I fix this?

Comment: Does it look pixelated in the file you're getting it from, your source image? If so, there's very little that anti-aliasing can do to help. The real benefit of AA in 3D is on the edges of geometry against their background. Specific texture AA you can do in Photoshop via softening filters if you're suffering with small artwork and sharp edges. Scale it up, then get at it with softening filters, then scale it back down to the desired size.

Comment: The real image is looks great and is it actually bigger than the geometry surface. Could it be too big?

Comment: I suppose there's a chance it's getting forcefully downscaled somewhere. It would need to be huge, though. Bigger than 2048*2048, at a guess.

Comment: nope, it is 500*500. strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting the material's `mipFilter` property to `SCNFilterModeLinear`